# how to save a file in vim using sudo?

Tags: vim

I want to map **w!** in vim to save a file using sudo **silently** (without need to press [Enter] and [L] keys).

Here is a line that works just perfectly:

```
command! W :execute ':silent w !sudo tee % > /dev/null' | :edit!
```

But it is **W**, not **w!** (with exclamation point)

How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builtin commands cannot be user-overridden.

You *could* however do

```
 :cnoreabbrev w! W
```

to 'magically' translate a lone `w` to `W`, which has the desired effect, AFAICT

Comment: @blackst0ne Missed that, fixed answer. This is pretty nice, at least from my testing! Gave your question the +1 for it